# Tkinter entry widget always selected for keyboard key presses

Tags: python, tkinter

I seem to have a hard time figuring this out, I want to always have a entry widget selected for keyboard input. So when I start the application, the widget should be selected for keyboard input, if I press a button the entry widget should still be selected for keyboard input, ect. How to do that?

So if I click another widget or in some other way select another widget the focus should return to the entry widget so that app always will accept keyboard key-presses in entry widget.

Comment: By "selected" dou you mean "has the keyboard focus" or "all the text in the widget should be sekected" (or bith)?

Comment: I'm new to gui terminology, but I tried to be more explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) might be helpful to you, checkout the `focus_set()` method.

Comment: YEAH! Thanks mate!